# Image levels: how to alter 'exposure' of dark and light areas?

Tags: image-processing

I was working with some less than ideal photographs, and wanted to adjust them before continuing. I wanted to raise the levels of the very dark areas and lower the levels of the very light areas. I couldn't find a function in Mathematica 8 that would allow me to do this. As a quick work-round, I wrote a function that quickly adjusted the levels. It looks terrible in this simplified example (I had more levels going, for one thing), but you get the idea (I hope!).

```
image1 = Image[
    ReliefPlot[
       Table[i - 3 Sin[i^2 + j^2], 
           {i, -4, 4, .03}, 
           {j, -4, 4, .03}]]]; 
tweakC = Compile[{pixel}, Module[{ p = pixel},
   m = Mean[p];
   Which[
        m < 0.3, p = pixel * 1.5,
            m > 0.85, p = pixel * 0.8 ,
            m > 0, p = p ]]];
image2 = ImageAdjust[ImageApply[tweakC, image1]];
ImageAssemble[{image1, image2}]
```

[image: before and after]:

What's the best way to do this? I don't think `ImageAdjust` or `ImageClip` do what I want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two things.

First, a minor point: if you rewrite your compiled function as

```
tweakC = Compile[{{pixel, _Real, 1}},
  Module[{m},
   m = Mean[pixel];
   Which[
    m <= 0.3, pixel*1.5,
    m >= 0.85, pixel*0.8,
    True, pixel]
   ]
  ]
```

then the `ImageApply` bit is 20 times faster (due to not having to use external calls). It's also a bit cleaner.

If you have v8 and a C compiler, you can speed it up by another factor of 2 by using `CompilationTarget->"C"`.

Second, and more important, is that your tone curve looks like this:

[image]

the jumps at .35 and .8 lead to harsh transitions. So I thought I'd use a smoother curve which you can interactively manipulate (horrible code, but seems to do the job):

```
image1 = Image[
   ReliefPlot[
    Table[i - 3 Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}]]];
DynamicModule[
 {pts = {{0, 0}, {.25, .25}, {.5, .5}, {.75, .75}, {1, 1}}}, Dynamic[];
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pts],
  Dynamic[
   curve = InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x];
   image2 = ImageAdjust[
     ImageApply[Function[{x}, Evaluate@curve], image1, 
      Interleaving -> False]];
   Dynamic[
    Plot[curve, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
   ],
   LocatorAutoCreate -> True
  ]
 ]
GraphicsGrid[
 {{image1, Dynamic[image2]}}
 ]
```

it looks like this:

[image]

The idea is, you define a curve by moving the locators, and the image on the right bottom reflects that transformation. The whole thing is interactive. You may add more locators by alt-clicking on windows and linux, cmd-clicking on OS X.

Note that I have little understanding of `Dynamic` etc, so this is probably badly written in terms of dynamic interactivity.

Comment: snap! I used `Erf` though.

Comment: @Verbeia 11 minutes faster (for once)!

Comment: I know, but it took me more than 11 minutes to write the answer, so I didn't realise you had posted it :)

Comment: @Verbeia of course. Although it would have been extremely impressive if you had typed up all that and uploaded the images in 11 minutes!

Comment: For `a>1/Pi`, your transformation function is downward-sloping in the middle. It is also not bounded between 0 and 1, which is necessary for this purpose. Values of `a` around 0.8-0.9 give quite psychodelic results :)

Comment: @Verbeia yes, I realize that. I'm not even sure what the question is, so this is a randomly-chosen curve...

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't too clear - i thought it wasn't too opaque, but anyway.  In some photographs shadows are too dark  - too much black - and there are blown highlights - too much white. Some kind of process that both lightens the dark areas and darkens the light areas was needed. Obviously the simple steppy function was just an example. I'll look at your ideas tomorrow. Thanks for these!

Comment: @Verbeia take a look at this :)

Comment: @cormullion yes, I thought you were trying to apply curves to manipulate contrast, but you simply say "not ideal photographs" so was not sure. Anyway, I think what I now present is flexible enough (but basically the answer to your question is that `ImageApply` does precisely what you want).

Comment: @acl that's pretty cool. Looking forward to trying it.

Comment: Basically, this works similarly to the curves tool in any image editor, see eg http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/photoshop-curves.htm

Comment: This is amazingly cool. It's cute how you implemented curves functionality using `Locator` and `Dynamic`.

Comment: @Mike much cheaper than photoshop! (and I lifted much of the code wholesale from the docs)

Comment: @acl Works brilliantly, thanks!

Comment: Neat - this is basically "Image>> Adjustments>>Curves" menu in Photoshop. The only suggestion is to add LocatorAutoCreate -> True option to LocatorPane[...] function so by pressing ALT+CLICK you can add or remove locators. For precision-crafting of the curve.

Comment: @Vitaliy Good idea, done!

Answer (score 11):

I liked @acl implementation of "curves". Here is a note on simple and effective image improvement. These is built in functionality in ImageAdjust[] :

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{image, ImageAdjust[image, {x, y, z}]}], {{x, 0, "contrast"}, 0, 
  1}, {{y, 0, "brightness"}, 0, 1}, {{z, 1, "gamma correction"}, .1, 
  2}]
```

[image]

Also this interactive interface is built in in M. Right click on the image, in context menu choose "Adjust Image" - and you can do it quickly via popped up interface, good for workflow.

[image]

Comment: I've got a couple more hours before I can upvote again, but +1!

Comment: @vitaliy that looks promising. It might do the trick, but I'll have to se if it modifies the mid-range of the photos...

Comment: @vitaliy But isn't this changing the whole image? Not just the badly exposed areas?

Comment: Yes but mostly in such a way that whole image improves. You cannot sharply distinguish between "bad" and "good" areas, in a typical meaningful image even "bad" areas are correlated with their "better" neighborhood, so to have no abrupt lines you have to modify the neighborhood too a bit. For more advanced techniques you can see M8 function  Inpaint[...]. Tone curve is also something to look at - bu this demonstration does not use Image Processing really, just shows general algorithm with pixels. I am sure it can be done better in M8: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ToneCurve/

Answer (score 7):

acl's answer addresses performance issue. I would like to address the design of your filter.

The fact that you are using a discrete function can't be helping. It will inherently create 'edges' in the graphic, even with more levels.

I'm also a bit confused by the fact that the output of your function is non-monotonic.

```
Plot[Which[m < 0.3, m*1.5, m > 0.85, m*0.8, m > 0, m], {m, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**EDIT** In fact my experimentation suggests that any function with kinks, let alone discontinuities such as the one you have used, will have problems with colour shifting.

I would suggest using a function that looks more like this, if you want to make dark areas darker and light areas lighter.  You can tweak the parameter 5 to taste.

```
Plot[0.5 Erf[5. (m - 0.5)] + 0.5, {m, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
tweakL = Compile[{pixel}, 
   Module[{p = pixel, m}, m = Mean[p]; 
    p = pixel *0.5 Erf[5. (m - 0.5)] + 0.5]];


image2 = ImageAdjust[
  ImageApply[tweakL, image1]]; ImageAssemble[{image1, image2}]
```

[image]

To *reduce* the contrast, you need to define a similar function that is smooth and has the desired slopes, much as acl has done

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with this and see if I can make the dark areas lighter and the light areas darker. But it looks like I didn't miss an obvious 'ImageExposure' function, which is something.