# How to use Rescale to make a brighter image?

Tags: image-processing, image

I want to compose three single exposures into an RGB image.

I have three 2D arrays that represent each exposure and I can combine them into a 3D array, specifying the RGB values for each pixel. My problem is that the third exposure is not bright enough, and I want to make it brighter.

If I want to make an Image brighter, I just use Lighter[image] and that sorts it. But in this case, I want to increase the brightness of only one of the three exposures, so I think I need to work with the array.

In the documentation, they state:

> ImageAdjust[Image[data]] is equivalent to Image[Rescale[data]]

How do I implement it?

---

What I have done:

Code for reference:

```
Module[
 {imageR = array5000/Max[array5000],
  imageG = array1000/Max[array1000],
  imageB = array100/Max[array100],
  rgb},
 rgb = Table[{imageR[[i, j]], imageG[[i, j]], imageB[[i, j]]}, {i, 
    pixels}, {j, pixels}];
 Export["buddhaBrot.jpg", Image[rgb]]
 ]
```

The result of

```
Image[array5000/Max[array5000]]
```

is too dark, whereas I would like it to be like

```
Lighter@Ligther@Image[array5000/Max[array5000]]
```

Comment: Wait ... if you know that you want `Lighter@Ligther@Image[array5000/Max[array5000]].`  ... why don't you just do that?

Comment: Also, what are `array5000` etc.?

Comment: Also, you can use the arguments of `ImageAdjust[image, {contrast, brightness, gamma}]`

Comment: BTW ... Have you seen this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9342/193 ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `ImageExposureCombine`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, convert your data arrays to images with `Image[]`.

If your `imageR` and `imageG` have good brightness, and `imageB` is too dark:

```
meanIntensity = Mean[ImageMeasurements[#, "MeanIntensity"]& /@ {imageR, imageG}]
badIntensity = ImageMeasurements[imageB, "MeanIntensity"]
imageBadj = ImageMultiply[imageB, meanIntensity/badIntensity]

combinedImage = ColorCombine[{imageR, imageG, imageBadj}]
```

should give you a color image with all channels appropriately bright.

Comment: It's not what I asked, but turns out you knew what I wanted better than me :)